# Getting jqGrid working for the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to get jqGrid to work, for the first time. I've copied an example, almost verbatim, and here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hi</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />

<script src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    height: 250,
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:100},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    multiselect: true,
    caption: "Manipulating Array Data"
});
var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"},
        {id:"7",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"8",invdate:"2007-10-03",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
        {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);

</script>

</head>
<body>

hi

<table id="list2"></table>
<div id="pager2"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

I know that my .js paths are correct, because the javascript console is not throwing any errors. Also, my stylesheet (jquery-ui-bootstrap) does indeed exist in that directory. (When I view-source and then click on the link to that CSS file, chrome correctly navigates me to it.)

The page, however, is only displaying "hi". Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is being executed before the table (`#list2`) is defined.

There are two easy ways to solve this, either of which will work:

- Move the JavaScript code to just before the `</body>` tag.
- Use jQuery's [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event to execute your code when the whole document has loaded.

Comment: Woah. That worked. I never would have guessed (I'm new to jquery - usually normal javascript works when defined in `<head>`, right? When I use document.getElementById() to update elements?)

Comment: You can't reference an element that doesn't exist yet (regardless of whether or not you're using jQuery). JavaScript in the `head` that references elements in the `body` only works if it's not executed until after the browser has read the `body`, e.g. if it's attached to some event like `window.onload`